# Contar cantidad filas en datagridview bajo una condicion

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Saludos utilizo para sumar la cantidad de deuda que tengo en un listado de facturas y la cantidad de factura que hay pendientes pero la cantidad de facturas no me esta funcionando, este es mi codigo:

```
       #region Calculo deuda pendiente
        double deuda = 0;
        foreach (DataGridViewRow item in dgvFactura.Rows)
        {
            deuda += Convert.ToDouble(item.Cells["Total"].Value);
        }
        CultureInfo DR = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("es-DO");
        DR.NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol = "RD$";
        lblpendiente.Text = deuda.ToString("C2", DR);
        #endregion

        #region Calculo cantidad de facturas pendientes
        int contar = 0;
        foreach (DataGridViewRow item in dgvFactura.Rows)
        {
            if (item.Cells["Estatus"].Value.ToString().Contains("Pendiente"))
            {
                contar = contar + 1;
            }
        }
        lblcantpendiente.Text = Convert.ToString(contar);

        #endregion
```

que estoy haciendo mal?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola, estas seguro de que existe en tu listado de facturas, existe alguna con **"Estatus" == "Pendiente"**?.

Comment: efectivamente el código estaba bien era la columna estatus que estaba mal escrita en el datagrid.

Comment: Estupendo!. Recuerda siempre valorar las respuestas que te han ayudado a solucionar tu pregunta, y marcar el check verde al lado de la respuesta que te ha solucionado la pregunta, con eso estarás colaborando con la buena salud de este sitio. Gracias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si vas a contar es mas facil si te ayudas con `linq` quedando

```
int contar = dgvFactura.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
                              .Where(r=> r.Cells["Estatus"].Value.ToString().Contains("Pendiente"))
                              .Count();
```

asi de simple en una sola linea lo resuelves.

Lo que si deberias verificar si verdaderamente esa celda de la columna de `Estatus` esta conteniendo esa cadena con la cual la comparas

Para sumar tambien es simple

```
double deuda = dgvFactura.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
                              .Sum(r=> Convert.ToDouble(r.Cells["Total"].Value));
```

Answer (score 0):

En primer lugar, deberías indicar en tu pregunta que **SI** existen facturas pendientes en tu listado de facturas, por que si no, nunca estarías aumentando el contador `contar = contar + 1;`.

En el caso de que existieran, tu código está aparentemente correcto:

```
    foreach (DataGridViewRow item in dgvFactura.Rows)
    {
        if (item.Cells["Estatus"].Value.ToString().Contains("Pendiente"))
        {
            contar = contar + 1;
        }
    }
```

Lo único que cambiaría es la asignación al `label` de la variable `int contar`. Hazlo de la siguiente manera:

```
lblcantpendiente.Text = contar.ToString();
```